# C# Deserialize JsonTextReader throwing OutOfMemory Exception

Tags: c#

I have an override for `ReadFromStreamAsync` as per below however I am getting an `OutOfMemory exception` in Newtonsoft's Deserialize call. The stream length is 28968933 which is roughly 27MB. It works for smaller-sized streams.

```
return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{                
    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(readStream, UTF8))
    {
        using (var jsonTextReader = new JsonTextReader(streamReader))
        {
            return serializer.Deserialize(jsonTextReader, type);
        }
    }
```

Comment: JsonTextReader returns tokens - http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/readjsonwithjsontextreader.htm

Comment: thanks for your reply however the link provided is not working